# What is the correct approach when combining React, Redux and React-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

My goal is to create SPA based on React using Redux and React-Router.

How should I store my location and history in order to create dynamic `Link` components?

e.g.:

```
<Link to={lastVisitedPage}> </Link>
```

Comment: Is `lastVisitedPage` the only thing you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

there are two approaches for this in your case;

First:

```
 <Route path="/" onChange={yourHandler} component={AppContainer}>
   <IndexRoute component={StaticContainer}  />
   <Route path="/a" component={ContainerA}  />
   <Route path="/b" component={ContainerB}  />
 </Route>

function yourHandler(previousRoute, nextRoute) {
   //do your logic here
}
```

then you can have your redux logic in yourHandler() function.
In the second way of doing this is to:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

//Your initialization

browserHistory.listen( location =>  {
 //Do your stuff here
});
```

have this in your app.js and have your redux logic in the listener.